# How to include partially-matched results in a cross-fields query?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

I'm building a [cross-fields search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_cross_fields_queries.html) using Elasticsearch 6.2. I'm having problems in figuring out how to handle partial matches for my term.

**My query:**

```
{
   "index":"course",
   "type":"course",
   "body":{
      "query":{
         "bool":{
            "must":{
               "multi_match":{
                  "query":"macroeconomics",
                  "fields":[
                     "course_name",
                     "course_number",
                     "university_name"
                  ],
                  "type":"cross_fields"
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "sort":[
         {
            "_score":"desc"
         },
         {
            "students":{
               "order":"desc"
            }
         }
      ],
      "from":0,
      "size":50
   }
}
```

The query returns decent results that exactly match the `macroeconomics` search term in the cross-fields mode.

**The problem is** that as soon as I change the search term to `macro`, I get a few results only for the `macro` term (exact matches), while my **expected results** would include:

- any results for the `macro` term (as an exact match), plus
- any results for the `macro` term (as a partial match), like e.g. in
  "macroeconomics"

I'm aware that using wildcards is performance-heavy, so that's not an optimal way.

**How do I adjust my query to get the expected results as described above?** It's not about treating "macro" as a prefix only, but as a potential substring available in other results.

Comment: Look at ngrams https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html

Answer (score 0):

Basically you will need to create a custom analyzer. For reference please check the [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html)

If you just want to give it a go.
To set up the NGram Tokenizer, we should declare as the following:

```
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "ngram",
          "min_gram": 3,
          "max_gram": 3,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

"my_analyzer" is the analyzer’s name that we will use for the ngram field
Then for your mappings, you need to map the analyzer to the field

```
 "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "course_name": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
        }
    }
    ...
```

Just add the analyzer to the fields that you want

***UPDATE***
Validate your analyzer

```
GET yourindexname/_analyze 
{
  "analyzer": "my_analyzer", 
  "text":     "macroeconomics"
}
```

The other one I have seen a lot is,

```
"min_gram" : "3",
"max_gram" : "8"
```

But it all depends on your use case.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. In the `tokenizer` config you use there, you set the min and max_gram to 3. That would mean that in my case, the tokens for "macroeconomics" would look like this: mac, cro, oec, con, nom, mic. As you see, the partial "macro" I'm interested in is not there which probably means it would not be found. Correct? If it's true, I'd need to use the value of `4` for the min and max_gram properties -- and then I would lose any 3 letter partials. This seems arbitrary because I'd like *any* partial to match. E.g. "you" should find "youtube"; "un" should find "unify", etc.

Comment: @lesssugar, yes you are correct. In my case 3, 3 was ok. In fact, that combination has always worked for me. but what I generally do is I will analyze the token using the _analyze api. You might have to play around for the proper min_gram and max_gram ngram values.